# Client ID and Sampling

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have a site that is on the brink of reaching the collection limits and would like to know some info on behaviours and effects of Sampling when a sampling rate is implemented and also when Google start to enforce Sampling.

Question 1: Does anybody know how Sampling works to ensure multiple visits by a Unique visitor give a true sampled view. By this I mean once a particular Client ID has started to be collected and included in a Sample will all future sessions for that Client ID be included or is this not guaranteed meaning only some visits by a particular client ID will be collected within the sample.

Question 2. As an extension to Question 1 does sampling across devices also ensure the same Client ID is collected i.e. PC Browser and Tablet Browser have the same ClientID set - will GA ensure both are included in the Sample.

Question 3. As an extension to the Quation 1 & 2 does Developer Implemented vs Google enforced Sampling cause different behaviours?

Question 4. As an extension to the above if I track a Web Site and App Session activity to the same account and use the same Client ID will Sampling ensure both are included.

Thank You

Comment: As for Question3, the way Google enforces sampling is by telling you that you should either implement sampling yourself or switch to GA Premium (or by shutting your account down if you don't comply within a reasonable timeframe). I have this in writing from a Google representative so I assume it's accurate information. So there is not difference between enforced and self-implemented sampling (and your account will happily collect data even if you're above the limits, it's just that then you are in violation of Googles TOS).

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I guess once google enforced collection Sampling is on its on and  once the following month starts its not turned off until the limit is reached again. Do you know if things like Overview Counts (Pageviews, Total Events) etc are collected and calculated without sampling i.e. these have the true totals?

Comment: Google never does sampling in data collection is my point (your reports might be based on samples, but that may happen even before your reached the collection limit. They do not drop hits even beyond the 10mio limit , and so they can choose samples for reports in a way that maintains the complete user path).